# IDE Error Occured - java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a problem with my Android Studio. Whatever project i run, this error occur. I had tried to delete android studio and reinstall Android Studio, but problem still occur. I don't know what to do. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
at com.android.tools.idea.emulator.EmulatorToolWindowManager.addEmulatorPanel(EmulatorToolWindowManager.kt:297)
at com.android.tools.idea.emulator.EmulatorToolWindowManager.access$addEmulatorPanel(EmulatorToolWindowManager.kt:58)
at com.android.tools.idea.emulator.EmulatorToolWindowManager$emulatorAdded$1.invoke(EmulatorToolWindowManager.kt:385)
at com.android.tools.idea.emulator.EmulatorToolWindowManager$emulatorAdded$1.invoke(EmulatorToolWindowManager.kt:383)
at com.android.tools.idea.emulator.EmulatorUtilsKt$sam$java_lang_Runnable$0.run(EmulatorUtils.kt)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:199)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:350)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:885)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:441)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:825)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:440)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:486)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBGco.png)

Comment: Seems like an AndroidStudio bug. Try updating AndroidStudio or reporting the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dan1st My Android Studio is latest version